# Calling a variable multiple times

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to call a variable multiple times, but it's only working on the one occasion. I'm guessing you are only able to use the variable once. Is there a way around this?

Here's an example of what i'm trying to achieve...

```
var prependThis = $('<li><a href="#">PREPEND ME</a></li>');
var andThis = $('<li><a href="#">PREPEND ME TOO</a></li>');
$(function () {
    if ($('body').hasClass('test')) {
        $(prependThis).prependTo($('.testing'));
        $(andThis).prependTo($('.test'));
    } else if ($('body').hasClass('anothertest')) {
        $(prependThis).prependTo($('.testing'));
        $(andThis).prependTo($('.test'));
    }
});
```

Comment: You can call that as many times as you want.

Comment: what variable are you trying to use more than once and where?

Comment: You're not calling any variable more than once. You're using elseif, so I can't understand your case.

Comment: If your variables only store a HTML string rather than a jQuery object, they will be reusable just like you want. But since you've made DOM Element Fragments, they are just moved around when you re-prepend them.

Comment: you know that you're trying to test `<body>` if it has the class `test` and `anothertest`, right?  not a div or something?  so you're looking for if `<body class="test">` else if `<body class="anothertest">`.

Comment: do you mean that you're trying to _call a **`function`** multiple times?_  this is messy but this is how your code is running for me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RG8fW/), and it `prepends` those things a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting a valid jQuery object with the selectors:

```
var prependThis = $('<li><a href="#">PREPEND ME</a></li>');
var andThis = $('<li><a href="#">PREPEND ME TOO</a></li>');
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

If you want to append a string you should just assign them in quotes to the variable:

```
var prependThis = '<li><a href="#">PREPEND ME</a></li>';
var andThis = '<li><a href="#">PREPEND ME TOO</a></li>';
```

This will be seen a HTML code when putted in the DOM.

so you can do:

```
$(function() {
if ($('body').hasClass('test')){
    $(prependThis).prependTo('.testing');
    $(andThis).prependTo('.test');
}
else if ($('body').hasClass('anothertest')){
    $(prependThis).prependTo('.testing');
    $(andThis).prependTo('.test');
}

});
```

note you did miss a signle quote here `$(prependThis).prependTo('.testing');`

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fe2f/2)**

Answer (score 0):

DOM objects can only be appended once.  You need to clone the jQuery element in order to be able to append it more than one time.

```
var prependThis = $('<li><a href="#">PREPEND ME</a></li>');
var andThis = $('<li><a href="#">PREPEND ME TOO</a></li>');

$(function () {
    if ($('body').hasClass('test')) {
        prependThis.clone().prependTo($('.testing'));
        andThis.clone().prependTo($('.test'));
    } else if ($('body').hasClass('anothertest')) {
        prependThis.clone().prependTo($('.testing'));
        andThis.clone().prependTo($('.test'));
    }

});
```

Comment: There's no need to make a jQuery object out of a jQuery object. `prependThis` is already a jQuery object, so you only need to clone it and append that to something. `var $clone = prependThis.clone(); $('.test').prepend($clone);`